# How much money in account is satisfactory for applying to Work and Live in Australia (Skilled Independent visa (subclass 189))?

Tags: working-visas, australia, pakistani-citizen

I am single, 25 years old, software engineer with 2.5 years of working experience. I want to apply for immigrant visa from Pakistan to Australia.

How much money in account is satisfactory for applying "Work and Live in Australia" category?

Applying for Skilled Independent visa (subclass 189).

Comment: too much questions in a single post. try to ask only one question per post.

Comment: thanks for reading my post. actually i have knowledge about below questions. i posted here all of them just in case somebody wants to share everything. Now question is only which is mentioned in title

Comment: note that expats.se is not a forum, but a q&a site. I edited your question to make it on-topic.

Comment: Which visa are you applying for? 457? Returning resident? Asylum? There are [at least a dozen possibilities, each with different rules](https://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/Find-a-visa.aspx?Purpose=Live+in+Australia&Nationality=Pakistan&ApplyFrom=Pakistan&Age=18-25&Stay=All&Length=All&Family=All&Type=All)

Comment: thanks for editing it for me. @MarkMayo i am applying for Skilled Independent visa (subclass 189)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions for visa subclass 189 do not stipulate minimum funds required, although they advise you should have enough money to settle as there are no welfare benefits for newly arrived migrants for at least 2 years.

In the case of the closely related state sponsored visa (subclass 190), some states have finance requirements for obtaining their sponsorship. For instance Victoria lists in its [Offshore table](http://www.liveinvictoria.vic.gov.au/visas-and-immigrating/skilled-visas/skilled-nominated-visa-subclass-190#OffshoreApplicantsTable), the value of $AUD 30,000 for single applications, 35,000 for one dependant, 40,000 for two dependants and so on.